# What's the best model GEE or lmer?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, meta-analysis, generalized-estimating-equations

I have access to individual data from 3 different studies. The first one has measurements of the variable of interest at baseline and 5 days after the intervention. the second one has measurements at baseline and 15, and 30 days after the intervention. the third has measurements at baseline and 60 days after the intervention. Individuals are different between studies and each study evaluate a different type of intervention. My objectif is to evaluate if there is a significant difference between baseline, 5, 15 , 30 and 60 days after the intervention and if intervention 1, 2, 3 and control group are significantly different adjusted for age and sex.

My question is: what's the best model to run to meet my objective ?

The depended variable is: Mascle masse (scale type)
The independent variables are: Interventions, Time, Age and sex.

This is a simulated dataset:

```
study1<-dataframe(
study=rep(1,100),
ID=rep(paste0("S1_",1:50),each=2)
)

study1<-study1 %>%
groupe_by(ID)%>%
mutate(Intervention=rep(sample(c("Intervention1","Control"),size=1),2),
Time=rep(c("Baseline","5days"),each=1),
Age=rep(round(runif(1,20,60)),2),
Sex=rep(sample(c("Male","Female"),size=1),2),
MuscleMass=rnorm(2,60,10)))
```

The 2 other datasets are similar to the first one, except Intervention and Time to change according to the study.